# Unable to attach a volume from Azure storage to my Kubernetes deployment

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-storage-account

I started recently experimenting with Azure cloud and K8s. I was trying to create a k8s deployment on my local machine (server) that only uses a blob storage from a storage account on Azure cloud.
I created a storage account, and copied its Key into a secret on the machine from which the deployment is deployed, then the following StorageClass, Persistent Volume. and Persistent Volume Claim:

Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: azure-storage
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
      - name: azure-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: current-pvc
```

Storage Class

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: azure-blob
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
parameters:
  storageAccount: gravitasexpstorageclass
  containerName: new-storage
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

Persistent Volume

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: persistent-volume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  azureFile:
    secretName: azure-secret
    shareName: container-name
    readOnly: false
  storageClassName: azure-blob
```

Persistent Volume Claim

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: current-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: azure-blob
  volumeName: persistent-volume
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

I'm expecting to find a new blob in my Storage account, but after a while, when I run

```
kubectl describe pod <pod name>
```

I get the following error:

```
0/1 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..
```

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here

Comment: Your StorageClass seems to be wrongly configured. You're using a parameter called `container` but the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#azure-file) in kubernetes.io don't show any such parameter.

Comment: Plus, your storage class needs to mention also the location of the storage account (Also, please don't put your storage account name and location on stack overflow for security reasons :) )